# Odd syntax: invoking a javascript function with two parenthesis pairs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am currently reading a book about AngularJS and I have a question regarding a javascript syntax that I don't understand.

```
var element = $compile('<button></button>')($rootScope);
```

How come the one can invoke a function with a **two** parenthesis pairs?

1. `('<button></button>')`
2. `($rootScope)`

Can anyone please advise about this js construct?

Comment: If `$compile` returns a function (which is completely legal) then this function can be invoked of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is no special construct, it is simply a function that returns a function.

```
function a () {
    return function () {
        console.log("hello");
    };
}

a()();
```

AngularJS `$compile` takes some HTML string and returns a template function which in turn can be called.

Your snippet of code, written over two lines, would look like this:

```
var template = $compile('<button></button>');
var element = template($rootScope);
```

Answer (score 2):

`$compile('<button></button>')` returns a function that is immediately executed by the second set of parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

`$compile('<button></button>')` calls a function. It returns something. `($rootScope)` is applied to the return value (which is presumably another function).

For a simple example:

```
function one() {
    return two;
}

function two() {
    alert("Hello");
}

one()();
```